# After allocating memory for a NSMutable array and adding the same to a NSMutableDictionary ,the Mutable array is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have allocated memory to a NSMutable Array by

```
NSMutableArray *typedBookCollection=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Now i am saving the array to a mutable dictionary.

```
[self.bookCollectionDictionary setObject:typedBookCollection forKey:bookType];
```

Output of the dictionary is

```
book details = {
    "Cookery Books" =     (
    );
    Others =     (
    );
    "Social Books" =     (
    );
    "Story Books" =     (
    );
    "Technical Books" =     (
    );
    "Travel Books" =     (
    );
}
```

I am adding books in the specified book array by the following code

```
for(Book *localBook in books)
        {
            printf("\n\nBook found in database=%i",[books count]);
            printf("\nBook type found =%s",[localBook.type UTF8String]);
            NSMutableArray *typedBookArray=[self.bookCollectionDictionary objectForKey:localBook.type];
            NSLog(@"\nGoing to add books in typed array=%@",typedBookArray);


            [typedBookArray addObject:localBook];
            //[[self.bookCollectionDictionary objectForKey:localBook.type]addObject:localBook];
            printf("\nOne book added successfully in typedArray=%s",[localBook.title UTF8String]);
            NSLog(@"\nBook details=%@",localBook.title);

        }
```

But whenever i  try to print it by NSLog it is *(null)*

Comment: It would help if you show the complete NSLog output. Which one exactly produces the "(null)" output?

Comment: Still you haven't provided enough info to help you. how have u allocated `bookCollectionDictionary` and `books`? show their code as well

Comment: NSLog(@"\nGoing to add books in typed array=%@",typedBookArray); this NSLog() produces the (null ) output

Comment: //-------------this is the out put after iterating through the for loop--------NSLog(@"\nGoing to add books in typed array=%@",typedBookArray); this NSLog() produces the (null ) output    Book found in database=4
Book type found = Travel Books 2013-09-09 11:58:37.192 BooksINCoreData[1163:c07] 
Going to add books in typed array=(null)

One book added successfully in typedArray=title

Comment: My dictionary and all the mutable array are allocated.....within this code block for(NSString *bookType in bookTypes)
    {
        printf("\nGoing to initialize the mutable array for book type=%s",[bookType UTF8String]);
        
        NSMutableArray *typedBookCollection1=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
        [self.bookCollectionDictionary setObject:typedBookCollection1 forKey:bookType];
        
    }

Comment: Your code will be cleaner if you use modern Obejctive-C:

    [self.bookCollectionDictionary][typedBookCollection] = bookType;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
printf("\nBook type found =%s",[localBook.type UTF8String]);
```

produces (according to your comment) the output

```
Book type found = Travel Books
```

which means that `localBook.type` is " Travel Books" with *a leading space*.
Therefore the following

```
NSMutableArray *typedBookArray=[self.bookCollectionDictionary objectForKey:localBook.type];
```

returns `NULL`: The dictionary does not have value for the key " Travel Books",
only for "Travel Books".

Answer (score 0):

Because you have dictionary of Array *(bookType)* and your have to add it in other dictionary *(book details )* and also your inner dictionary *(bookType)* has empty array so whenever you may be try to print it by `NSLog` it is (null)

Comment: The NSLog output of an *empty* array is `()`, and not `(null)`.